# Arbitrary union of sets in topological space

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

In my text on topology, the term *arbitrary union* constantly appear without the author having state the definition. Google search didn't quite give me a satisfactory answer either.

In simple terms, what exactly is *arbitrary union*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, ''arbitrary'' is used to note that the union doesn't need to be taken over a finite or even countable number of sets. That is, the cardinality of the indexing set for the union is arbitrary.

Comment: Yes, the word "arbitrary" here has the same meaning as in "arbitrary number", "arbitrary function", etc. If you like, you can simply omit it.

Comment: So really, it just means taking 'as much as I want', whether up to a fixed arbitrary index or to the tune of finitely many. Is this correct?

Comment: It's just an adjective used in order to emphasize that no special request is made on the family of sets we take the union of, whereas a topology is only closed with respect to ***finite*** intersections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\Lambda$ be an index set. Take a family of subsets $\{U_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ of the set $X$. The union $$\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}U_{\lambda}$$ is called *arbitrary union of the family* $\{U_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$.

Obs: $\Lambda$ can be any set that you want.